# Nesting ScrollViewers when top level uses deferred scrolling doesn't behave correctly

Tags: wpf, nested, scrollviewer

I have a control which at its core looks like this:

```
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
             ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" Name="w_Carousel">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        CanVerticallyScroll="False"
                                        CanHorizontallyScroll="True"
                                        />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

It holds objects, which themselves may have a scrollviewer. Simplified, they look like this:

```
    <ScrollViewer Width="160"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False">
    <Label>THIS IS SOME REALLY LONG TEXT AND EVEN MORE </Label>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

When I grab the scrollbar for the inner control, the outward one responds. What's up with this? It looks like a bug in WPF but I'd have a hard time believing this got through QA. How do I have deferred scrolling on the outer scrollbar, but have the inner one not have deferred scrolling, and have this function correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this myself just now.  There is a potential solution here (at end, by omdsmr):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f95f4727-5e84-48da-b153-973128292172

It says:

> I found that the problem is that commands from the child scrollviewers 'leak' up to the main scrollviewer.
>
> You can stop the command routing by adding an input binding.
>
> Add this to any UIElement descendant of the main scrollviewer that is also an ancestor to all of the child scrollviewers:

```
<UIElement.CommandBindings>
<CommandBinding
 Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.DeferScrollToVerticalOffsetCommand}"
 CanExecute="OnDeferScrollToOffsetExecuted" />
<CommandBinding
 Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.DeferScrollToHorizontalOffsetCommand}"
  CanExecute="OnDeferScrollToOffsetExecuted" />
</UIElement.CommandBindings>
```

> Then this handler in the code behind:

```
void OnDeferScrollToOffsetExecuted(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
 e.Handled = true;
}
```

I never tried this myself yet.  Haven't decided if I want to use deferred scrolling.